# xlsxwriter set_column to hide doesn't work

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to hide a column with XlsxWriter but it seems not working. The function returns 0 that means that the column has been hided with success.

I'm using column with number and not with letter.

```
workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('SENSORS').set_column(5,5, None, None, {'hidden': 1})
```

However, the columns don't be hide.
Why the statement doesn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work. Here is a simple example based on your snippet:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('SENSORS')

workbook.get_worksheet_by_name('SENSORS').set_column(5, 5, None, None, {'hidden': 1})

for col_num in range(8):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, col_num)

workbook.close()
```

Output, note that column 5 is hidden.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the problem was that I opened the .xlsx file with Numbers on macOS.

Comment: I just tried with Number 6.2.1 on macOS and the column/data is hidden as well.