# How to make a csv file with hidden columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to create a csv file like this with python ?

Comment: comma-separated values file (CSV) doesn't contain any extra information as the data. You can see it as a txt file. You would need something like a .xls file to have these feature from excel.

Comment: `csv` does not support hidden columns. It is only possible with Excel file.

Comment: Side note: Excel is *not* CSV - don't conflate the two.

Comment: @SangkeunPark Is there a way to do hidden columns with .xls ?

Comment: @Ajex That's new to me, thanks

Comment: In this case I think "hide" just means "shrink to minimum width".  The column is still there, and any non-beginner will know how to restore it.

Comment: @AndySu Please explain why you need to know this and what is your purpose. It is necessary to answer you question.

Comment: Look into xlrd for example if you need .xls specifically, or openpyxl or xlsxwriter if you need the newer .xlsx format.

Comment: @SangkeunPark I’m doing a function that can make people download data from my website.So they can edit as they want and upload to update. the problem is: each one of row data has an ID which isn’t necessary to show. That’s why I want to hide it.

Comment: @AndySu Then, it is impossible to use .csv file like that. csv is very simple, just comma seperated text file.

Comment: @SangkeunPark Yes, I'm making this feature with a different format now.

Comment: Don't use obscurity as security. Instead, make an efford to display the ID (don't make it sequential - you could use a GUID - and inform that updates are only made if the ID is correct (plus maybe add some one-time-pin for the user, to prevent GUID spoofing).

Comment: Well, if they download, update, and upload, how will you know how to match up their update with the original if the ID is missing? (assume that they can and will change row order, even if accidentally)

Comment: for people who are looking for the same:https://stackoverflow.com/a/59859458/11757001。

Comment: Oh, that's a great explanation of what's going on. Have you tried that?  And, how well do you know Python?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple script for dropping the third column from an input CSV and writing out the modified CSV.

Here's my sample, **input.csv**:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1,i,a,A
2,ii,b,B
3,iii,c,C
```

Here's how it looks in a grid:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
| 1    | i    | a    | A    |
+------+------+------+------+
| 2    | ii   | b    | B    |
+------+------+------+------+
| 3    | iii  | c    | C    |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Here's the script:

```py
import csv

in_file = open('input.csv', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(in_file)


header = next(reader)  # manually iterate to get first row from the reader
print(header)          # a row from the reader is just a list of strings
header.pop(2)          # remove "3rd column" by calling list's pop() method
print(header)          # list is now just three strings, missing 'Col 3'


out_file = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(out_file)
writer.writerow(header)

for row in reader:    # automatically iterate the readeriterating 
    row.pop(2)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Here's **output.csv**:

```
Col1,Col2,Col4
1,i,A
2,ii,B
3,iii,C
```

```
+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | Col4 |
+------+------+------+
| 1    | i    | A    |
+------+------+------+
| 2    | ii   | B    |
+------+------+------+
| 3    | iii  | C    |
+------+------+------+
```